# How to import map property of rxjs in angular project , Error : Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Object>'?

Tags: angular, typescript, http, rxjs, mean-stack

I am posing the data on the server in angular with http post request and with rxjs but even after importing map property of rxjs this is giving an error.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient,HttpHeaders,HttpErrorResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
import {throwError } from 'rxjs';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {


  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  registerUser(user){
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('content-type','application/json');

    return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/users/register',user,{headers:headers})
          .map(response =>response.json())
          .catch(this.errorHandler)

  }


  errorHandler(error:HttpErrorResponse){
     return throwError(error.message||"Server not responding");
  }
```

}

i even import map property like this:

```
import {map} from 'rxjs/add/operator';
```

**Error:**

```
Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Object>'
```

**User is a object**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using RXJS 6 or above, the usage of operators has changed a bit.

You import by:

```
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

You use the map inside of the pipe operator, like:

```
return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/users/register',user,{headers:headers})
      .pipe(
          map(response => {
              // doSomething 
          }),
          catchError(error => {
              this.errorHandler(error);
              return of(`Caught an error: ${error}`);
          })
      );
```

Comment: It is now giving an error on response.json() i.e property 'json' down not exist on type 'object'

Comment: @JoelJoseph is right, HttpClient returns json by default, so no need to call json().

Comment: So then how can I call catch or catchError  function bcz it's  giving the same error for catch function

Comment: @ShivaChandel check my answer now

Comment: @ShivaChandel What is the error you get when running this code?

Comment: While compiling the  error is property 'catchError' does not exist on type ' Observable<object>'

Comment: Can you double check that you import it like "import {catchError} from 'rxjs/operators'", and that you use it inside the pipe like "pipe(catchError())". You are not supposed to dot chain it like ".catchError()".

Answer (score 0):

- From RxJS v6 and up, support for calling operators directly on `Observable`s are deprecated. Instead, use `Observable.pipe`.
- From RxJS v6 and up, support for directly importing operators has been deprecated. Instead, import from `rxjs/operators`.
- `HttpClient` (from `@angular/common/http`) by default maps responses as JSON. No need for the `map` operator (this is the former behaviour for `Http` (from `@angular/http`)).

See below for a corrected example:

```ts
import { /* imports go here */ } from '@angular/common/http';
// ...

// ...
export class AuthService {
  // ...

  registerUser(user){
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('content-type','application/json');

    return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/users/register',user,{headers:headers})
          .catch(this.errorHandler);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using RXJS 6 or above, you have to pipe the operation

```
 this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/users/register',user,{headers:headers})
 .pipe(map(response => {
   // do something with response and return it
 })
 catchError(this.errorHandler)
  );
```

also if you are using `HttpClient` instead of `Http` then there is no need for `response.json()` as response  will be deserialized json.

Comment: did you try my answer ?

Comment: Yes I did but it's not working it is giving an error i.e property 'json' does not exist on type 'object'

Comment: there is no need for using `.json` as my answer

Comment: that is no need for doing this step `response =>response.json()`

Comment: As you said HttpClient by default maps responses as JSON. So there is no need of using .json() and of pipe also but this is giving the same error while I am using .catch() operator

Comment: @ShivaChandel `catch` has been renamed to `catchError`! Thanks

Comment: I even tried this but still the error is property 'catchError' does not exist on type ' Observable<object>'